# Angular get reference to element to custom attribute directive inside of a projected template with ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, ng-template, angular-content-projection

I'm having an issue modifying the css and click event on a [custom attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

The `DIV` in question is inside of a reference to a projected `' and passed into a nested child.

Here is how it works

add the ng-template to the parent.

```html
<parent>
  <ng-template #editCellTemplate>
    <div customUpdateDirective>Update</div>
  </ng-template>
  <Child1>
    <Child2>
      <Child3> RENDER editCellTemplate IN HERE </Child3>
    </Child2>
  </Child1>
</parent>
```

The parent passes the refence to `#editCellTemplate` to child3 with an observable

```
export class Parent {
  // ...

  @ContentChild('editCellTemplate') public editCellTemplate?: TemplateRef<any>;

  // ...parent

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.editCellTemplate)
      this.editService.updateEditCellTemplate(this.editCellTemplate);
  }
}
```

Here is the `customUpdateDirective`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customUpdateDirective]',
})
export class CustomUpdateDirective {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(el); //issue here is el is a reference to the parent component and not the div the attribute is attached to.
  }
}
```

inside of child3 I have this html to render the reference to the editCellTemplate in the loop:

```html
<Child3>
  <!-- this renders the template in a for loop. Everything displays correctly -->
  <div *ngfor...>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="editCellProjectedTemplate"> </ng-container>
  </div>
</Child3>
```

The issue is when I have a  reference to the directive `customUpdateDirective`, it's a refrence to `ParentComponent` and not the `Div`

```
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [CustomUpdateDirective],
})
export class Child3 implements OnInit {
  editCellProjectedTemplate!: TemplateRef<any> | null;

  private customUpdateDirective: CustomUpdateDirective;

  onInit() {
    this.editService.editTemplateObservable.subscribe((editTemplate) =>
      this.setEditTemplate(editTemplate)
    );
  }

  setEditTemplate(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    if (Object.keys(template).length < 1) return;

    //setting the template renders the div inside of editCellProjectedTemplate for Child3
    this.editCellProjectedTemplate = template;

    //the problem starts here
    this.customUpdateDirective.el.nativeElement; //nativeElement is the a reference to the Child3 container and not the div it's instantiated on
  }
}
```

How can I get a reference to the Element `<div customUpdateDirective>Update</div>` that the `customUpdateDirective` is applied to when referencing a template? I want to add a click event and style the css.

Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hgbjeu?file=src/app/child4.component.ts)
I've used DI to pass in the template for the demo instead of an observable. How can I get access to the custom element with the editDirective in the SB example?

Comment: The custom directive needs to be registered. I plan on having mutliple Parent components so I need to make sure it doesn't interfere with outside components. I put it in the provider of Child3 because if I don't  it will have a reference to the ParentComponent inside of the directive. Child3 was the closest component I can get to while getting a reference to the customUpdateDirective. I hope that made sense

Comment: @Drenai  putting there was more of an experiment. I still can't get a reference to the div with constructor injection in the directive. It's always referencing the parent component.

Comment: @Drenai Thanks I'll set one up

Comment: @Drenai I've set up a stackblitz if you would to take a crack at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppModule`, register the `directive` to be available to other components in the app via `declarations` and `exports`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [
    ...
    Child4Component,
    EditDirective,
  ],
  exports: [EditDirective],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can also remove `providers: [EditDirective],` from the child component